# Is it possible to have multiple audio outputs?

Tags: audio, audio-output

I have two screens attatached to my PC, one is a standard desktop monitor and the other is a TV. I dont use them at the same time.

The TV is connected via HDMI to my graphics card (ATI Radeon 5750) which picks up audio from the motherboard to send to the TV.

My desktop monitor is attached via DVI but it has built-in speakers, so they are attached via a standard audio jack on the back of the motherboard.

Is it possible to send the audio through both outputs continuously, so that I can switch between monitors without also having to switch audio outputs?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Note: I have the [ASUS P6T Deluxe](http://www.asus.com/Product.aspx?P_ID=vXixf82co6Q5v0BZ) motherboard if that helps.

Comment: What OS? Are you saying you're switching the audio output in control panel/etc? You're not physically changing any audio outputs, correct?

Comment: Im running Windows 7. Yes, physically everything stays the same. I just want to know if its possible to have the graphics card and the motherboard sound card outputing audio at the same time or if the PC can only route it through one way or the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you don't have the various outputs muted it should work fine. HDMI carries both video and audio. The last laptop I worked with, an HP with HDMI, was able to produce sound through both HDMI and headphones at the same time. I believe this is what you are asking.

Look at your audio settings, they are either managed by windows or a utility that your manufacturer provided. It will show all the possible audio outputs and you should be able to mute/unmute at will.

Answer (score 1):

Might have a look at [Virtual Audio Cable](http://software.muzychenko.net/eng/vac.html) (commercial, 35.70 USD).